# How to delete a string with the same word and consecutively increasing number in a text file using a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

For example I have:

```
Hello1 :
Hello2 : 
Hello3 :
```

How Could I delete all of these with a shell script. The number reaches up all the way to 1000.

Comment: Have you tried `sed -i '/^Hello[0-9][0-9]*[ ]:/d' filename`? If there is additional text after the `':'` (or you want to delete the entire line) you can use `sed -i '/^Hello[0-9][0-9]*[ ]:.*$/d' filename`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '/^Hello[[:digit:]]\+\>/d' file.txt
```

Or, if you want to output to a different file:

```
sed '/^Hello[[:digit:]]\+\>/d' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: You could add a bit more explanation that will get you a few upvotes and an acceptance.

Comment: Well, it involves a little bit of knowledge into sed.  The gist is the d is a deletion command, and the thing before it is the regex to match lines to apply the command to.  Any more detail would be an explanation of ed grammar or regex grammar.

Answer (score 2):

If you  wish to delete all the lines that contain only `Hello(number) :` use below :

**Sample Input** in `file`

```
Hell
Hello1 :
No hello stuff here
Unjulating stuff
Hello2 :
Some sentence
Hello99 :
```

**Script**

```
sed -Ei '/^Hello[[:digit:]]+ :$/d' file
```

**Sample Output** in the modified `file`

```
Hell
No hello stuff here
Unjulating stuff
Some sentence
```

**What happens above**

1. Using the `^` in the pattern we check for the beginning of the line.
2. We check the pattern `Hello(number) :` using `Hello[[:digit:]]+ :$`. Note that I used -E to enable sed extended regular expressions so I need not escape the + ie (`\+`). Here `[[:digit:]]` is a class which contains
   all the decimal digits and `+` is used to check if the pattern before it matches at least one time.
3. Check the end of the line using `$`
4. For a matched pattern, delete it line using the `d` option
5. I have also used the sed `inplace edit` option `-i` so that the changes
   are directly saved to the file.

If you wish to change the a line the begins with `Hello(number) :` then use the below script

```
sed -Ei '/^Hello[[:digit:]]+ :/d' file
```

You might have notices that I just removed the `$`, so our pattern matches any line that starts with `Hello(number) :`

Hope this helps.